# How to change text color of legend in d3js graph?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph, legend

Title; I'm following [this tutorial on a stacked bar chart.](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/43f10523858abf6053ae) I have a black background and wanted to change the color of the legend to white.  I have already done so with the axis, but can't seem to edit the legend text.  I tried

```
.legend {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 60%;
    color: white; //added, but doesn't work
}
```

From what I can tell, this code:

```
svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "legendLinear")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(height+30)+")");
var legend = d3.legend.color()
        .shapeWidth(height/4)
        .shapePadding(10)
        .orient('horizontal')
        .scale(color);
```

creates the legend, but I have no idea how to modify the text label that labels the legend.

As you can probably tell, I am very new to d3 and javascript, and am very lost.
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

EDIT: I added this to the CSS but it removed the label completely instead of making it white (you can check this by changing the background of the tutorial to gray):

```
.legendLinear{
     fill: '#ffffff'
}
```

EDIT2: I changed it to:

```
.legendLinear text.label {
     fill: '#fff'
}
```

and it doesn't seem to work either; the text is still black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do using CSS:

```
.legendLinear text.label {
   fill: '#fff'
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me, the legend labels are still in black text

Comment: are you sure, seems to work in the [link](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/raw/43f10523858abf6053ae/) you provided.

Comment: yea; where did you put the javascript portion?

Comment: where did you put the css one? was it under the .legend?

Comment: In class legendLinear , i dont think there is any legend class being added.

Comment: what do you mean by class legendLinear?

Comment: like this?

svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "legendLinear")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(height+30)+")")
            .legendLinear text.label {
   fill: '#fff'
}

Comment: just add the CSS, no javascript changes required

Comment: I updated the post with the new CSS edition and it seems to make the legend label not appear at all

Comment: like I mentioned earlier there is no class called legend being used. just add the style to legendLinear like in my answer. BTW, you cant nest css selectors like you have done in your edit unless you are using any css pre-processor.

Comment: where did you put the css?  I updated the post to show what I have tried

Answer (score 3):

```
    .axis path {
    stroke: white;
}
   .axis line {
    stroke: white;
}
   text { 
    fill: white;
}
```

http://codepen.io/tcasey/pen/dXKrBx

Here's a working example to reference

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
legend.style("fill", '#fff')
```